# 'PythonModelContext' object returned from mlflow.pyfunc.load_model - how to retrieve original model that was saved

Tags: python, mlflow

I am creating a custom [myflow.pyfunc](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#) object that I would like to save to MLFlow and retrieve later. I don't understand the relationship between the object that is saved with `mlflow.pyfunc.save_model()`, and the one that is retrieved with `mlflow.pyfunc.load_model()`.

The loaded model is a 'PythonModelContext' object rather than my original python class. When I try to use the predict method in the loaded version I get an error.

Here I initialise MLflow and create a dummy example of my class

```
# load 
import os
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import mlflow
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
import mlflow.pyfunc
from mlflow.pyfunc import PythonModelContext

# initialise MLFlow
mlflow_var = os.getenv('HYMIND_REPO_TRACKING_URI')
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(mlflow_var)   

client = MlflowClient()

# Define the class that will be used for fit and predict (dummy example)
class PredictSpeciality(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    
    def fit(self):
        print('fit')
        d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        return df
           
    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        print('predict')
        print(X.shape)
        return
```

If I now run the class as it is the predict method works:

```
# Use of this predictor before saving works fine 
m = PredictSpeciality()
df = m.fit()
m.predict(df)
```

But if I save the model to the registry, and then re-load it, the predict method no longer works:

```
counter +=1
exp_name = 'MLflow-test-' + str(counter)

os.environ["MLFLOW_EXPERIMENT_NAME"] = exp_name
experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment(exp_name)

mlflow.set_experiment(exp_name)
experiment = dict(mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(exp_name))
experiment_id = experiment['experiment_id']

with mlflow.start_run():
    
    # dummy code here for fitting a model
    m = PredictSpeciality()
    df = m.fit()
    
# mark best run
runs = mlflow.search_runs()
best_run_id = runs['run_id'][0]

# tag the best run and save model
with mlflow.start_run(run_id=best_run_id):
    mlflow.set_tag('best_run_', 1)   

    mlflow_model_path = f'/data/hymind/repo/{experiment_id}/{best_run_id}/artifacts/model/'
    mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path=mlflow_model_path, python_model=m)
    
# end experiment and register best model
model_name = 'MLflow-test' + str(counter)
registered_model = mlflow.register_model(f'runs:/{best_run_id}/model', model_name)

# now attempt to make a prediction using the loaded model
model_version = 1
m = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(f"models:/{model_name}/{model_version}")
m.predict(df)
```

In this case, I get the attribute error

> AttributeError: 'PythonModelContext' object has no attribute 'shape'

How do I get the original model back from the 'PythonModelContext' object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a close look at the signature of the abstract method `predict()` in the [mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py#L88) class that you are extending, you will see that has 3 parameters:

```py
def predict(self, context, model_input):
```

So, if you change your simple class to have the extra parameter `context`, your example should work:

```py
class PredictSpeciality(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def fit(self):
        print('fit')
        d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        return df
           
    def predict(self, context, X, y=None):
        print('predict')
        print(X.shape)
        return
```

To elaborate a bit more on what is going on here:
There are 2 classes at play: [mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py#L62-L96) and [mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py#L363-L442).

The mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel is being wrapped by the mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel. The former is doing the actual work and the latter is dealing with the metadata, packaging, conda environment, etc. In the [documentation](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py#L21-L30) it is explained like so:

> Python function models are loaded as an instance of
> mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel, which is an MLflow wrapper around the model
> implementation and model metadata (MLmodel file).

Unfortunately, the [documentation also states](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py#L367-L369) that you cannot create a PyFuncModel directly, but only

> Wrapper around model implementation and metadata. This class is not meant to be constructed directly. Instead, instances of this class are constructed and returned from `mlflow.pyfunc.load_model()`.

I find that quite limiting and am unsure why it was designed this way, however, there are 2 things that you can do here:

1. Pass in an extra parameter when directly dealing with your wrapped class:

```
   m.predict(None, df)
```

2. Save and load the model to get an mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel:

```
   mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path="temp_model", python_model=m)
   m2 = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("temp_model")
   m2.predict(df)
```

I know it isn't elegant, but I actually have been using #2 in the past. It would be good if someone from the MLFlow team could comment on why direct creation of a mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel is not supported.

Comment: with this solution, m.predict() works for the re-loaded model. However, m.predict() fails on the earlier step, before saving the model, with this error "predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'. 

It seems like an additional parameter needs to be specified.

Calling m.predict() on the re-loaded model returns the 'PythonModelContext' object which, presumably, is the context referred to in 'def predict(self, context, X, y=None)' but I'm not sure how to pass or refer to this object when calling other methods.

Comment: I added some more details on the limitations of the PythonModel/PyFuncModel concepts -- I don't think they are particularly well chosen trade-offs, but I believe, they can be worked with.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the very useful advice. This answers my question. I simplified my problem as posted here, so while this solution is great, it doesn't solve my original problem. I have done a follow-up post which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74257370/mlflow-pyfunc-load-model-mlflow-pyfunc-save-model-how-to-pass-additional-art. I agree with you and others that the MLFlow documentation could be more helpful on the use of custom python functions